# How can I find the value of Custom Attribute of the Anchor Tag?

Tags: jquery, custom-attributes

I have an anchor with two Custom Attributes. The one with the asterisks is added later.

The HTML code is below:

```
<ul class="dropdown">
      <li class="orange"><a href="#" data-jumpslide="2" **goto-page="newpage"**><div class="list-item one-liner"><div class="left"><span id="functionality-icon"></span></div> <div class="right">When to do it</div><div class="clear"></div></div></a></li>
      <li class="orange"><a href="#" data-jumpslide="3" **goto-page="newpage"**><div class="list-item one-liner"><div class="left"><span id="functionality-icon"></span></div> <div class="right">Key faces</div><div class="clear"></div></div></a></li>
      <li class="orange"><a href="#" data-jumpslide="5" **goto-page="newpage"**><div class="list-item one-liner"><div class="left"><span id="functionality-icon"></span></div> <div class="right">Functionalities</div><div class="clear"></div></div></a></li>
 </ul>
```

I want to get the value of this newly added Custom Attribute in the below Jquery code. For some reason **attr** is not working.

Do you have any idea how it might work:

```
$('a[data-jumpslide]').each(function(idx, ele){
    $(ele).on('click', function(){
        alert($(this).data("goto-page"));
        var slideToJump = $(this).data('jumpslide');
        window.slider.go(false, slideToJump+1);
    });
});
```

thanks.

Comment: you're not even using attr anywhere in that code

Comment: Like Cory said, you either have to actually use attr or change the attribute to data-goto-page and use .data('gotoPage') to access it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for this to work your HTML-attributes should start with `data-`:

```
<ul class="dropdown">
      <li class="orange"><a href="#" data-jumpslide="2" data-goto-page="newpage"><div class="list-item one-liner"><div class="left"><span id="functionality-icon"></span></div> <div class="right">When to do it</div><div class="clear"></div></div></a></li>
      <li class="orange"><a href="#" data-jumpslide="3" data-goto-page="newpage"><div class="list-item one-liner"><div class="left"><span id="functionality-icon"></span></div> <div class="right">Key faces</div><div class="clear"></div></div></a></li>
      <li class="orange"><a href="#" data-jumpslide="5" data-goto-page="newpage"><div class="list-item one-liner"><div class="left"><span id="functionality-icon"></span></div> <div class="right">Functionalities</div><div class="clear"></div></div></a></li>
 </ul>
```

Then your jQuery can retrieve the values just fine:

```
$('a[data-jumpslide]').each(function(idx, ele){
    $(ele).on('click', function(){
        alert($(this).data("goto-page"));
        var slideToJump = $(this).data('jumpslide');
        window.slider.go(false, slideToJump+1);
    });
});
```

Comment: It isn't working, it gives me an alert with a message of "Undefined" ... sorry.

Comment: If you switch the alert-line with the slideToJump-line, do you get a value into slideToJump?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the data prefix, you can do this:

http://jsbin.com/etebil/1/edit

```
$('a[data-jumpslide]').each(function(idx, ele){
    $(ele).on('click', function(){
        alert($(this).attr("goto-page"));
        var slideToJump = $(this).data('jumpslide');
        window.slider.go(false, slideToJump+1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JSFiddle that shows an alert of the `.attr` value: http://jsfiddle.net/Ndpfd/

Looks like the problem was that you used `ele` instead of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .attr method.

```
$('a[data-jumpslide]').each(function(idx, ele){
    $(ele).on('click', function(){
        alert($(this).attr("goto-page"));
        var slideToJump = $(this).data('jumpslide');
        window.slider.go(false, slideToJump+1);
    });
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/